A multiple single source of truth problem
I was recently studying state management (flutter provider), and in every example I saw it was necessary to create a single source of truth so that the data could be read and updated in the application. However, in an authorial application of mine I came across the need to dynamically create several instances of a controller class.
This is the screen I am working on:
Its a carousel builder, that builds a list of widgets with given data, there is many screens in this configuration that can be accessed, so I need multiple instances of a controller;

This is the controller class I created (not complete yet):
class SelectedItemsController {
  Map<int, List<int>> itemCods = {};
  Map<int, List<bool?>> boolList = {};

  SelectedItemsController(this.itemCods , this.boolList);
}

I was trying to do this: Every time I click on an Item, the controller class will update the item cods, and later I will use the data to rebuild this screen for each slider, if needed, but I dont know if I can create multiple instances of the controller for each screen with this configuration. Any suggestion?

The meaning behind having a "single source of truth" for your data is so that you aren't having to worry about the same data being stored in multiple places, forcing you to write convoluted and error-prone synchronization logic. There's nothing saying you need to have a single place to store ALL of your data (unless you subscribe to the Redux school of thought, at least). You can have multiples of these controllers, each one delivering data to a particular view. Of course, you can also go the Redux route by making a single model that wraps all these controllers in a single Map or something.
